# Are all balls the same weight?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

A few days ago [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92254/are-all-balls-the-same-weight) was asked on puzzling.SE:

> There are 10 balls which come in two possible weights. Using a balance scale at most 3 times, determine whether all the balls are the same weight or not.

The [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92264/293) is not terribly satisfying, because there's no obvious way to generalize it.  Can it be generalized?

**Given N balls, how many weighings are required to determine if all balls are the same weight**?  Equivalently, for a given number of weighings, what's the maximum number of balls we can weigh?

Comment: Have you established any general result?  Is it, say, obvious that $w_ n≥w_{n-1}$ (where $w_n$ is the minimal number given $n$ balls)?

Comment: I guess it's clear that $w_n≤w_{n-1}+1$ since you can always handle the first $n-1$, in $w_{n-1}$ moves, and then weigh one of those against the odd man out.  But it's not immediately clear to me that the sequence can't go down (though it would certainly be counter intuitive).

Comment: More generally we have $w(k) \le w(n) + 1$ for all $ k \in \{n+1, n+2, \dots 2n\}$, by the same logic, i.e. handle $n$ first, then weigh some/all of these "good" ones vs the remaining $k-n$.

Comment: @antkam: Right, and that leads to the obvious algorithm to do $n$ balls in $\lceil \log_2{n} \rceil$ weighings (mentioned in the original question) by weighing 1v1, then 2v2, then 4v4, etc. But, as can be seen by this question, that algorithm is not minimal.

Comment: (A) Prodded by the great comment by @lulu I have actually been trying to prove $w(9) = 3$ without success so far.  We have $w(8) = 3$ (binary method) and $w(10)=3$ (the original puzzle), but is $w(9) = 3$ or is it possible $w(9) = 4$??  (B) The binary method works even without the constraint "the balls come in _at most two_ possible weights".  I guess we shouldn't have been _toooo_ surprised that adding the constraint makes the problem easier...

Comment: @antkam: The binary method does not work with three weights. Ex. 2+2 = 1+3 would balance

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - oh!  you mean 3 different weights.  you're absolutely right - my (B) comment was wrong.  well then the $w(10) = 3$ solution is even more mysterious.  :)

Comment: I finally had to write some code to search: $w(9) = 3$ e.g. ({0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}), ({0, 1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6, 8}), ({0, 1, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 4, 5})

Comment: @antkam: Try using your program to solve for other values of w(n) and see if the resulting sequence exists on the OEIS

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - sadly my code is pretty brute-force, and it had a hard time even finishing the $w(11)$ case.  there are lots of symmetries i have not taken advantage of, which would greatly reduce the search space.  if/when i have time to optimize, i'll certainly post any results here.

Answer (score 1):

$N=30$ for 4 weighings:

Let's divide all 30 balls into several groups. Namely, let in groups
there will be 2, 5, 6, 8 and 9 balls. If we use four equalities to prove that the weights of the groups are also related as $2:5:6:8:9$, then we will solve the problem.

The required equalities are:

2+6 = 8

2+9 = 5+6

5+9 = 6+8

2+5+8 = 6+9

Let $w_2$, $w_5$, $w_6$, $w_8$ and $w_9$ be weights of our groups. Then $w_2+w_6=w_8$, $w_2+w_9=w_5+w_6$, $w_5+w_9$=$w_6+w_8$ and $w_2+w_5+w_8=w_6+w_9$. So, we solve and conclude that $w_6=3w_2$, $w_8=4w_2$, $w_5=2.5w_2$ and $w_9=4.5w_2$. If both balls in 2-group are the same (with weight $m$) then $m=w_2/2 = w_5/5 = w_6/6 = w_8/8 = w_9/9$, so all balls are equal. If balls from 2-group are not the same, then $w_2=M+m$ and $w_5=2.5(M+m)$, i.e. $2m+3M < w_5 < 3m +2M$, that's impossible.

So, the proof is over.

Comment: Sorry my linear algebra is a bit rusty.  Does your proof rely on the fact that you have $5$ unknowns and $4$ equations and the relevant $5 \times 4$ matrix has rank $4$?  If so can you more fully explain the reasoning?  It might be obvious to others but as I said my linear algebra is rusty.  Thanks!

Comment: This shows that it's possible to do N=30 in 4 weighings, but not that 3 weighings isn't possible, nor that N > 30 in 4 weighings isn't possible.

Comment: I don't know proof that $N>30$ is not possible.